# Estou fazendo um projeto onde preciso criar uma listagem de herois em reactjs, html, css e javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, react

tenho o projeto já feito em html, css e javascript. porem não tenho muita experiência com reactjs, gostaria de saber se tem como inserir react nesse site já pronto ?

segue meu código abaixo.

```
<!--responsividade-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/responsive.css">

<!--owl css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/owl/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/owl/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<title>SUPER HERO</title>
```

SUPER HEROIS DC

```
<main>
    <div class="filme-principal">
        <div class="container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>


<div class="carrosel-filmes">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
               <a href=""><img class="box-filme" src="img/ajax.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!--linkar as imagens a link externo-->
                <a href=""><img class="box-filme" src="img/Batgirl.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href=""><img class="box-filme" src="img/superman.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href=""><img class="box-filme" src="img/lanternaverde.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
               <a href=""><img class="box-filme" src="img/aquaman .jpg" alt="" srcset=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="box-filme" src="img/cyclops.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="box-filme" src="img/flash .jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="box-filme" src="img/mulhergaviao.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="box-filme" src="img/mulhermaravilha.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="box-filme" src="img/robi .jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2c36e9b7b1.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl/setup.js"></script>
```

Comment: Poder pode, agora você deve ponderar se é conveniente.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eu recomendaria usar o vite para fazer a criação automática, mas se já tem o projeto pronto é facíl implementar o react seguindo as informações do site oficial: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html.

Primeiro precisa fazer um container no html principal da sua página, um div com id root onde o react poderá manipular seu app, a gente chama de div root.

Em seguida adicione a tag de scripts do react que até o momento são estas recomendaveis:

agora precisa adicionar um component para ligar o react ao DOM abaixo

e dentro dele:
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
ReactDOM.render(e(SeuComponent), domContainer);

e pronto

se quiser ir além pode configurar o webpack